# Rally Web Services REST API - Ruby Toolkit

Tags: rally

I'm trying to update the Project an artifact belongs to. I am not getting any errors but the artifact's Project does not change. I can successfully change the artifact's notes, name, and other attributes, but not Project. I'm not sure if I'm specifying the Project name correctly in the call:

updated_artifact = @rally.update(:hierarchical_requirement, "FormattedID|" + artifact.FormattedID, {"Project.Name" => "Project A"})

Answer (score 0):

Got help from CA Support and resolved this. If you want to update an associated/referenced field, you'll need to send the URL reference to the Project and supply whatever the OID of the project is, like so:

updated_artifact = @rally.update(:hierarchical_requirement, "FormattedID|" + artifact.FormattedID, {**"Project" => "/Project/OID"**})